# Where validate input params? In the controller or in the service class, used by controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to stick to principles of thin controller and thin model. And I believe that business logic related code should be in the service classes.

I write a Rails back-end application accepting JSON requests. And I need to validate, that the one parameter is present. Let's assume that I have:

```
class UserController
  def change_status
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    render json: UserStatusChanger.new(user, params[:status]).perform!
  end
end

class UserStatusChanger
  attr_reader :user, :status

  def initialize(user, status)
    @user = user
    @status = status
  end

  def perform!
    # complex logic here
    {result: 'ok'}
  end
end
```

And now let's suppose that I need to receive **non-blank params[:status]**. Sure, in the real world it is much more complex with more parameters. :)

My question is: **Where should I put validation of params[:status]?**

My thoughts are:

1. If I put it in the controller, I need an integration test to test the validation. But there are some good looking solutions, as [rails_params gem](https://github.com/nicolasblanco/rails_param). But I can face with problem of big controller method, having many validations. And also in the unit test my service will work wrong if some input parameter is `nil` without validation before performing complex logic.
2. If I put is in the service, the test will be more lightweight. But I should catch exceptions via `ApplicationController#rescue_from` and this will be not tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that you should do it in controller. As for me, i usually do it in `before_action` method. According to MVC pattern, all params and routing logic must be in controller.

Comment: In this case, how do you test services? Only via 'positive tests'?

Comment: I testing my controller with a different params and in controller I just expect, that my service will receive. Complex logic in service i testing in service test.

Comment: But what if the validation is not simple and it requires some `UserStatusChanger` logic? Make public methods like `#valid_status?` and then call them in `UserController#validate_user_status`? Having `before_filter :validate_user_status, only: [:change_status]`?

Comment: But in this case we need two tests. One for UserStatusChanger#valid_status? and second for UserController#validate_user_status. Am I right?